# arrows sloped on a tikz edge aren't straight

Tags: tikz-pgf

When using `\underleftarrow` on an equation sloped on an edge, the arrow does not look straight. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0)  {a};
    \node (b) at (2, 8) {b};
    \draw (a) to node[above,sloped]
    {\(\underleftarrow{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\)} (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix it?

Comment: When I zoom into a pdf that was generated from your source, they become straighter and straighter. I suspect this is just caused by aliasing. You sometimes also see it with compound mathematical delimiters: on the screen you can see the joins but when you print them you can't.

Comment: You should be aware that `\underleftarrow` is produced by connecting a number of dashes; when rotation is involved, these small parts can *appear* as forming a jagged line, but this is due to the PDF viewer trying to snap to the raster (remember the screen has a much lower resolution than a printer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to solve this problem once and for all, it is not hard to switch to Ti*k*Z's own arrows

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0)  {a};
    \node (b) at (2, 8) {b};
    \draw (a) to node(c)[above=10,sloped]{$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$}(b);
    \draw[->](c.south east)--(c.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```